# Webrtc in Android webview

Tags: android, webview, webrtc

We have developed webapplication on Webbased Video / audio communication, in the backend, it uses webrtc + html5,

Now we are trying to make it native, and approach is

-- Developed a WebView, 
-- Launch an URL in the webview, so it will be more of native app . just a embededding webview as a shell inside the native app,

-- Now My question if i am able to launch Video Communicator successfully inside Browser then in the same device, should it launch in the Native application ( which is using WebView as a shell)

Answer (score 1):

Well you could go native/hybrid, on Android for example, you could use Crosswalk/Angular/Ionic, I've tested a video chat app prototype with this method and it worked pretty well.

Crosswalk runs Google's Blink engine over Androids WebView, this is awesome for older android versions and phones that aren't super new because.
1. Gives the latest HTML features including WebRTC to about 85% of all android phones.
2. Performance is great, it's hard to tell between hybrid or native, the Crosswalk/Angular/Ionic stack is very smooth.

I've seen a couple iOS hybrid solutions as well out there, just haven't got around to trying it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just responded to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933532/using-webrtc-in-native-app/16963176#16963176) on Stack Overflow:: Android WebView does not support WebRTC APIs at this point. Work is underway on Java an Objective-C bindings, though that may not be what you need.