# Using Webrtc in Native App

Tags: android, ios, android-webview, webrtc

My questions is :

1 -- Is it possible to have a WebView( Provided by Native framework) instance in my Native App , and extend it to support Webrtc,

if 1 is Yes, then probably following would be the action Item

1 -- Have a webrtc build on Android, 2 -- In Android WebView extend Javascript to couple / bind the Webrtc call,

Please confirm..

## What i am trying to do is

1 -- We have webrtc based Voice / Video chat application working fine in Chrome & Mozilla desktop Browser, as both comes with webrtc... , i.e. user need to access www.xyz.com and it will start video / voice sessions,

2 -- same thing on mobile, we would like to go as a native app, i.e. we are trying to make an application, which will have native WebView instance, in which we will access www.xyz.com to have voice / video session

3 -- I tried the way i explained in 2 but it seems, in WebView instance provided by Application framework doesn't have webrtc enabled in it, so i am trying to add it and this is what i am thinking,

-- WebView instance has some mechanism to extend the Javascript , that means 
http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html 
some of these API i need to add into the WebView, and for their implementation will come if i am able to successfully integrate and build Webrtc over android and iOS Platform

Please comment....

Comment: hi Amitg2k12, i see your comment.but i have no idea about what you wanna do.say you wanna use a WebView in app,and extend to support webrtc.what confused me is which is the focus,WebView or webrtc itself?if webrtc is the focus,why use WebView,webrtc itself can be build and use on android,there's no need to use WebView and JS.and if your app has already structured with WebView and just wanna adding webrtc featrues into it,i should say sorry cus' i have no info about webrtc with JS,i'm just build the standalone audio processing modules of webrtc with JNI+NDK. so please say more clearly :)

Comment: @billhoo : thanks for looking at it, i have edited question accordingly, hope it will have more clarity for now..

Comment: i got your point. but i have no experience on WebView developing. and WebRTC seems not support mobile browsers right now. anyway, i find so many folks are asking the same question as you did, and find these sites 1.https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/discuss-webrtc/XiMzboUM-ic/2luLWmB_i0YJ 2.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352237/does-phonegap-support-webrtc 3.http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream may help you a little, hope i helped.

Comment: I think this link involves every answer related to `Audio_Processing` whether it is *Pre-Processing* or *Post-Processing*: [Android_Audio_Processing_Using_WebRTC](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android-Audio-Processing-Using-WebRTC), You can also visit this reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58546599/10413749

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is kinda old, but I find crosswalk (https://crosswalk-project.org/) to be a pretty good solution for using WebRTC inside of an Android app. What crosswalk do, is compiling a chromium browser into an Android app and hosting your site inside of this chromium, so you will have support for the latest browser features, like WebRTC.

Comment: Crosswalk is no longer necessary if you're using the WebView in Android L/5.0 or higher

Comment: Crosswalk currently has a major bug when it come to WebRTC: https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-7030

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use webRTC in a Native App, i've built a small android app (https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC) that share the back camera to a nodeJS server (https://github.com/pchab/ProjectRTC).
I found that the easiest way to use the libjingle library is with IntelliJ IDEA. I've had a lot of problems with Eclipse and Android Studio.

Comment: Hey! Both of your links are broken. Are you still hosting these repos somewhere?

Comment: links are working, but the problem is i am unable to setup this server. they says it will be UP on 3000 port. but it is crashing :(

Comment: Now its easy with Android Studio by adding dependency - implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+'. Check out this [sample project](https://github.com/duttaime/webrtcandroid).

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have a hard time with the WebView, although it's coming on (newer) Android at least. Nothing on the horizon for iOS.

If you want complete native, you can check out what we've done @ FM with [IceLink](http://www.frozenmountain.com/downloads#icelink), sounds like it might work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Android WebView does not support WebRTC APIs at this point.

Work is underway on Java an Objective-C bindings, though that may not solve your problem.

Comment: Today WebView V36 supports WebRTC https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

Answer (score 2):

With Android L release this should be possible by using just the Android WebView, more below :
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#WebView

Answer (score 1):

I'm building a native app with a webview and webrtc video inside.
So generally it is possible to build such application and nowadays chromium (webview) have a official support https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview , but I have faced really a lot of problem during writing that application.

Few problems are:

- Support for phones and os version - I have android 5.1.1 (xperia m2) and after a lot of problems webrtc is running. On android 6 (xperia z5 compact) is not working.. On other phones is sometimes working sometimes not...
- You can not be sure, how webview will work - today webrtc is working, but tommorow Google can add some security rule, and it will not work- it's a little bit unstable, and as I have seen, some things depend on os compilation. WebView can get update from store independently of os.
- PERMISSIONS - there are a lot of stupid problems, based on the fact that is it a browser inside native app, like - you can't expect a permission question from webview, you have to implement it in android webview config, and in some android versions it is working- in others not :-)
- Still a lot of problems of 'young product' - example is that nowadays webview has some issue with devices info display (like camera is front or back) so you have to find a workaround for such problem
- Bad video quality - currently my problem is a quality of video- nice quality of video on phone, below maximum resources consumed (cpu, network, memory) and video on computer is really poor...
- ...and many more

So the fact is - yes this is possible, but it's still not good enough to use it without facing a lot of problems which are not so easy to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually go native with html5 features. So if you use Crosswalk as someone mentioned before, but if you are really set against using:  Crosswalk/Ionic/Angular/Cordova (which is awesome), you can still use Crosswalk in a native environment to replace inconsistent and feature lacking WebViews with 1 single, full WebRTC compatible WebView based on the Blink Engine.

I remember reading a few guides on how to get Crosswalk going in Android Studio, here's one I quickly searched, but just Google around there's a bunch of them.
https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/34721/How-to-use-CrossWalk-runtime-within-an-A